# create parameters for all my Power Query files

Tags: excel, parameters, powerquery

I would like to create parameters available in all my Excel files with Power Query, is it possible?

I gave you a screenshot of what I mean by parameters

[image: create parameter on power query]

I searched the internet I did not see any resource on it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You should be able to do this from the Home tab on the ribbon:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello and happy new year 2021!
Thank you for the answer !
Sorry if I only answer now, I was on vacation ...
I misspoke. In fact, I would like my parameter to already exist on all the Excel files I'm going to create without going to "New Parameter". I don't know if I'm clear ... I don't speak English well, sorry about that.